# Как определить необязательный параметр в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
(vk.com\/video_ext.php\?oid=([\d]+)&id=([\d]+)&hash=([a-z0-9 ]+)((&hd=[\d])|(sd)+))
```

как сделать, так, чтобы регулярка срабатывала при наличии и отсутствии на конце

```
((&hd=[\d])|(sd)+)
```

Comment: `?` - указывает что группа может отсутствовать

Comment: (=?(&hd=[\d])|(sd)+) так? на https://regex101.com/ не получилось завести регулярку

Comment: нет, после группы `(..ваша группа которая может отсутствовать....)?`

Comment: @Grundy ответы предпочтительно оформлять как ответы. а не комментарии, даже если вопрос кажется Вам примитивным.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ну может это опечатка была и закрыть надо :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Квантификатор `?` указывает на одно совпадение или ни одного совпадения.

Таким образом достаточно поставить его после нужной группы

```
((&hd=[\d])|(sd)+)?
```