# Регулярные выражения. Что в этом случае означает ".?"

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext()){
    String eingabe = sc.nextLine();
    String newengabe = eingabe.toLowerCase();
    String [] array = newengabe.split(" ");
    if (array[0].equals(array[1])){
        System.out.println("richtig");
    }else

        for (int i = 0; i<array[0].length();i++){
            String regex = "^"+array[0].substring(0,i) + ".?("+array[0].substring(i);// ar.sub выводит от i и до конца
            if (i<array[0].length()-1){
                regex = regex + "|"+array[0].substring(i+1);

            }
            regex = regex +"$)";
            if (array[1].matches(regex)){
                System.out.println("ok");





        }//else if (!array[0].equals(array[1])&&!array[1].matches(regex)){
             //   System.out.println(false);
            //}

    }



}
```

}
}

Comment: Любой знак, один или ни одного раза. А откуда этот кусочек кода?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить необязательный параметр в регулярном выражении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490104/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: private static String iEqual(String word1, String word2) {
        if (word1.equals(word2)) {
            return "richtig";
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < word1.length(); ++i) {
                String regexp = "^" + word1.substring(0, i) + ".?(" + word1.substring(i);
                System.out.println(regexp);
                if (i < word1.length() - 1) {
                    regexp = regexp + "|" + word1.substring(i + 1); }
                regexp = regexp + "$)";
                if (word2.matches(regexp)) {
                    return "ok";

Comment: Что это за код? Пожалуйста, объясните, что вы хотите: добавьте код в вопрос, приведите пример  строки и желаемый результат. Поясните, что у вас за проблема. Если вы просто хотели узнать, что делает квантификатор `?`, согласитесь, что это дубликат и закройте  вопрос.

Comment: спасибо. Я изменила. Я не могу понять значение кода после for loop. Суть задания - сравнить два слова и если они одинаковы , то выдать "richtig" , а если отличие в одной букве , тогда выдать "ok".

Answer (score 2):

. --- любой символ кроме символа конца строки, а ? - это квантификатор(обозначает кольчиство повторений предыдущего, именнно ? -- [0, 1]])

Comment: Насчёт - `? = [1, ,бесконечность]`- Вы уверены?

Comment: Да,  уверен,  можно ещё так указывать.{55,66}

Comment: Спасибо, не перестаю восхищаться открывая для себя что-то новое. Не подскажите пожалуйста, что то у меня [тут](https://regex101.com/r/fvtcmg/1/) не получается? Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Извини,  что продезинформировал,  я исправил ответ